# Probability distribution based on random events with increasing weights

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider a weighting function, f(t), that is monotonically increasing with the time, t. [This may not be strictly necessary, as pointed out in the comments, but all of the cases I am actually interested in have that property].

At regular intervals, we conduct a random 50-50 trial (coin flip) ... if it succeeds, we "win", and get to add the value of f(t) to a "cumulant" function, c.  If the trial fails, we "lose", and have to wait for the next trial.

So, if we discretize the weighting function $f(t)$ such that $f_i$ is the value at the i-th sampling interval, then after n trials we can express c as:
$$
c=\sum_{i=1}^nf_iX_i
$$
where $X_i$ is a Bernoulli random variable with mean 0.5 (thanks to user21820 for explaining correct notation/terminology).  What I am interested in is the probability distribution function $P(c;n)$ describing the probability of obtaining a given value of c after a particular number of trials, n.

The expected shape of the distribution for certain choices of $f(t)$ is pretty clear .. for example if $f(t)$ is constant, then $P(c;n)$ is just a binomial distribution, and I am pretty sure that if $f(t)$ is an exponential, then $P(c;n)$ should approach a log-normal distribution as n increases.  I am more interested in the case where $f(t)$ is given by a simple power law, e.g. $t^2$.  Is there a "named" probability distribution corresponding to that case?

Comment: Why would f(x) increase exponentially? Also you're mapping a continuous domain (the nice smooth reals) to a DISCREET (nth flip) one, which means you have to partition it into buckets (eg, flip 1 is 0<x<=1 and flip 2 is 1<x<=2 .... ) what are you trying to do exatly?

Comment: Increasing weights, you say you're adding 1?

Comment: As I said, I am sampling an increasing function (which I am calling the "weight") at regular intervals, based on the results of a series of 50-50 trials.  If a trial succeeds, then I add the current value of the increasing function to my total (which starts at 0), otherwise I wait for the next trial.  

I am interested in the general way to find the distribution of values of my total after a given number of trials, for an arbitrary monotonic function f(x). I can certainly model this process using a computer, but it seems to me that there should be a way to figure it out analytically ..

Comment: Got an example or 2 of what f does when you get heads or tails, remember for me to answer properly I must get WITHOUT ANY AMBIGUITY what you are doing, f(t) may seem obvious to you but it may not be the obvious notation to me.

Comment: f is independent of the results of the trials ... it's just a function that is increasing with monotonically with time.  It's only there to supply the value that gets added to the cumulant function c, when a trial is successful.

Comment: I don't follow sorry, what's the problem? (I've read it a few times)

Comment: If you can model this using a computer, you certainly need to declare all your variables before using, but in your question what is $t$ and $c$? I may be able to guess your question, but better for you to be as precise as you should have been in a program.

Comment: @user21820 I guess I don't understand your issue .. $t$ and $c$ are both defined above in plain language ... $t$ is time and $c$ is the "cumulant" function, which I use to keep track of the amount I have "won" in all the successful trials.  

Example: Say $f(t)=t^2$, we are sampling every 5 seconds and the results of the first 5 trials are $(1,0,0,1,0)$ (1=success, 0=failure).  The value of $c$ will just be the summed value of $t^2$, counting only the successful tests, or 425.  If the first 5 trials instead go $(1,0,1,0,1)$, then $c=875$. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: @dtmoore1971: I'm not the only one who doesn't find it precise enough. I could not even have guessed that "5" in "5 seconds" was actually important to you. You could have just asked for $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) X_k$ where each $X_k$ is a bernoulli random variable with mean $\frac{1}{2}$. If that is what you actually want, then that one line is all you need have asked. Whether $f$ is monotonic doesn't make a difference either.

Comment: @user21820  Great, thanks.  Obviously I didn't write that because I didn't know how to express it that way .. I am not an expert in this stuff, and I had never heard of a Bernoulli random variable.  I will re-write the question accordingly.

FWIW, the "5" in "5 seconds" wasn't important to me .. that is just a potential way of building an example around what I actually wrote.

Comment: Oh okay. In that case I doubt there is anything you can really get unless $f$ is a special kind of function.

Comment: You can get the mean and variance by just summing up the individual means and variances, because the random variables are independent. Beyond that, there's little that you can obtain for general $f$, I think.